# 'CwConfirmLotConfig' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: typescript

New to TypeScript. I'm trying to run build but getting this error.

`Error: 'CwConfirmLotConfig' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

```
import { CwConfirmLotConfig } from './cw-confirm-lot-config.model';

describe('CwConfirmLotConfig', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(new CwConfirmLotConfig()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

and here is the cw-confirm-lot-config.model.ts

```
export interface CwConfirmLotConfig {
  monitorType: string;
  tempalteType: string;
  patternIdKeyword: string;
  tempalteId: string;
  createUser: string;
  updateUser: string;
  createDate: string;
  updateDate: string;
}

export interface CwConfirmLotConfigUpdateData {
  create: CwConfirmLotConfig[];
  update: CwConfirmLotConfig[];
  delete: CwConfirmLotConfig[];
}
```

Comment: Well, it _is_ an interface, not a class that would have a `new` operator.

Comment: There are two scopes: one for types and another one for values. You can mix them only if you have a deal with class constructor or enum. You dont have neither class nor enum